# Secure password prompt before executing script

Tags: javascript, security

I am using JS for password validation before executing the script. My query is, how do I make it more secure cause the password is easily visible in View source?

```
function password_protect() {
var pwd = prompt ("Enter the password", "");
if (pwd != 123) {
alert ("Wrong password!");
return false;
} else {
return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Serverside validation with an AJAX call would work. But it's rather pointless since the script that you don't want to be executed is also visible in the source and can just be called directly. But if you just want to make it a little harder, then you could use a base64 or md5 string instead of plain text.

Comment: OP why not deploy the file to amazon S3? Amazon S3 allows you to attach username/password combos to files. Do *not* write your username/password 'validation' in the source files. It should be handled at the server level

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check password validity in the backend. You can do it by posting it to the backend service, where you would compare it to the constant.

Otherwise, there is no safe way of keeping passwords in the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Your password will always be visible in the source if you store it in javascript. There is no way to make it even "a bit secure". Javascript is client-side.

Why do you need to validate in js? try validating in php at first and execute the js based on that result instead.

Comment: There's no way of keeping a password secure if you write it into the source of *any* language. The only thing the code should know to do is 1) where to find the password and 2) what hashing algorithm (bcrypt) it uses. You should always assume the code of your language is exposed to people who want to do potentially nefarious things no matter how much you obfuscate it :P